# `ng build --prod` fails with `ERROR in TypeError: Cannot read property 'version' of null`

Tags: node.js, typescript, angular5, ng-build

I can't successfully get my project to build with the `--prod` flag [it builds fine otherwise].  I can temporarly add `maxMetadata &&` to the if statement where the error occurs to null check and get passed that point (metadata_reader.js line 66) and then I get a list of "real" issues related to a production distribution; but I'd like to get some insight as to why it is happening in the first place and see if there is a permanent fix.  I have managed to find similar issues around and have tried much of what other people have tried, but it doesn't seem to be exactly the same issue and have yet to find a resolution.

Versions:

```
Angular CLI: 1.6.5
Node: 8.9.4
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 5.2.3
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

@angular/cli: 1.6.5
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.0.42
@angular-devkit/core: 0.0.29
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.0.52
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.9.5
@schematics/angular: 0.1.17
typescript: 2.7.1
webpack: 3.10.0
```

Full stack trace:

```
ERROR in TypeError: Cannot read property 'version' of null
    at readMetadataFile (C:\git\screenings-plus\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\transformers\metadata_reader.js:66:29)
    at Object.readMetadata (C:\git\screenings-plus\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\transformers\metadata_reader.js:35:25)
    at TsCompilerAotCompilerTypeCheckHostAdapter.getMetadataFor (C:\git\screenings-plus\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\transformers\compiler_host.js:425:34)
    at StaticSymbolResolver.getModuleMetadata (C:\git\screenings-plus\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:29726:62)
    at StaticSymbolResolver.hasDecorators (C:\git\screenings-plus\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:29426:46)
    at analyzeFile (C:\git\screenings-plus\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:31299:63)
    at AotCompiler._analyzeFile (C:\git\screenings-plus\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:30509:17)
    at AotCompiler.findGeneratedFileNames (C:\git\screenings-plus\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:30525:42)
    at Object.findGeneratedFileNames (C:\git\screenings-plus\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\transformers\program.js:397:82)
    at TsCompilerAotCompilerTypeCheckHostAdapter.getSourceFile (C:\git\screenings-plus\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\transformers\compiler_host.js:337:55)
    at findSourceFile (C:\git\screenings-plus\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:74915:29)
    at args (C:\git\screenings-plus\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:74852:85)
    at getSourceFileFromReferenceWorker (C:\git\screenings-plus\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:74825:34)
    at processSourceFile (C:\git\screenings-plus\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:74852:13)
    at processRootFile (C:\git\screenings-plus\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:74706:13)
    at C:\git\screenings-plus\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:73855:60
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the issue, I placed a `console.log(maxMetadata.version);` on line 66 of the metadata_reader.js and was able to get a lead to where the problem was, which turned out to be a metadata file [*.metadata.json] within my project.  It had `[null]` which needs to be `[]` for all current versions of Angular.  Once this was changed, I was able to get a normal `ng build --prod` build readout.